# AMD on Windows: blue screen after waking from suspension

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, bsod, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card

I'm getting a blue screen of death every time I suspend and wake up a freshly installed Windows 10 PC with an AMD Radeon 4550.

**Stop code:** `VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE`

**Error in:** `atikmpag.sys`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

this [VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE/Timeout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x116---video-tdr-error) is an AMD graphic card driver issue. The Radeon HD 4550 is a legacy card and never got an Windows 10 driver. The last [driver is from 2013](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2064).

Install this driver and hope that it fixes the issue, otherwise buy a newer card that gets updated drivers.

Comment: Windows automatically installs the driver, when I downloaded it from AMD it said it was already installed. When I removed it in device manager it reinstalls itself. Anyways I'll try using the old driver.

Comment: if windows already offers you this driver, get a new card.